# How to resolve module not found error in JupyterNotebook for tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I have created the tensorflow environment using the following set of commands:

```
conda create --name py3-TF2.0 python = 3

conda activate py3-TF2.0
conda install tensorflow
pip install -upgrade tensorflow
pip install ipykernel
```

[image]

Comment: I've found out that currently tensorflow doesn't support Python 3.9 and since i was using Python 3.9, i was facing the above issue. So for that i created a new virtual environment and used the same above command with a little tweak python=3.8 and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps to install Tensorflow using Conda

```
#create virtual environmenttf2.0 using conda 
conda create --name tf2.0 python=3
#Activate the env
conda activate tf2.0
#Install Tensorflow
tf2.0$pip install tensorflow
tf2.0$python
#Verify the Tensorflow installation before launching any of the IDE
>>import tensorflow as tf
>>tf.__version__


#Launch the jupyter notebook
tf2.0$conda install jupyter
tf2.0$jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is run the jupyter notebook and try installing tensorflow from there.

In a jupyter notebook cell type in:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

(dont miss the ! sign before)

To test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```